# SQL database design advice needed

Tags: sql, database, database-design

**My Database:**

```
CREATE DATABASE `cars` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cars`.`employees`;
CREATE TABLE  `cars`.`employees` (
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cars`.`products`;
CREATE TABLE  `cars`.`products` (
  `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prod_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_price` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prod_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

That is my database query. I have task to create database of CARS which contains informations about employees and cars, also the database must contain information about which car is sold and which worker sold it.

**My Question:** How can I store a sale, so that I record which employee has sold which cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design decision that goes over the 1NF direction you ( or somebody else over your organization ) must considerate prior to development. To respond your concrete question, this is the typical case where a XRef table is needed to put together all the Customer-Vehicle associations along with extra details refered to the solds. 
Ie:

```
Sale table: 
-----------------------------
sale_id autonumeric(1,1) PK
, emp_id int FK
, prod_id int FK
, price decimal(10,2)
, sold_date datetime(2)
, other_interesting_sale_details
```

This is one possible solution that will keep historical info about which car was sold by a specific employee plus additional details it may be of interest for the particular business.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly create a table for holding which employees sold which cars?

```
EmployeeSales
---------------
emp_id
prod_id
OtherInfo
```

Comment: Depending of the `products` table contains the models of the cars of the cars entities itself. In that case, you do not need another table. `products` should contain a foreign key to the `employees` table and a `status` field.

Answer (score 0):

depends on how expansive you want to go... you have a products table... will this be it for your cars and every car will just be added to this directly?   If so, then you could just tack on two fields

In the products table, add a column "SoldBy" as integer.  This could be a link to the employees table Employee ID.

if the value is populated, it's sold, and if sold, it is the employee who sold it.